# Getting Undefined index: login_session after log out in the CodeIgniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter.
I am working on the login page. There is no issue with login. I am getting the issue on login session.

I set if there is no login session then it will redirect on login page else redirect on the dashboard page.

Now I tried below code but it's not working properly. I am getting the error "Message:  Undefined index: login_session"

What I did, I logged in the portal(Now I am on dashboard page ) and I just copy the URL and paste it on next tab. So it shows me my dashboard page correct. Now I log out from the second tab and after that, I refresh the first tab then it shows me `Undefined index: login_session`. So according to the first tab also redirect on the login page. correct?

Also sometimes I am on the portal and within few second my session logout.

```
public function index()
  {
    $this->checkLogin();
  }

public function checkLogin(){
  if(!($this->session->userdata('login_session')))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_id', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        $this->load->view('member/login');
                 }
                 else
                {

                    $custid = $this->input->post('customer_id');
                    $password = $this->input->post('member_password');
                    $result=$this->Member_model->check_password($custid,$password);//varifying password
                   if ($result) {
                        //creating session

                            $login_emp_session = array('firstname' => $result->first_name,'lastname' => $result->last_name);
                            $this->session->set_userdata('login_session',$login_emp_session);//set the session 
                            redirect("Member_controller/dashboard");

                        }


                   else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid_password', 'Invalid username and password');
                    $this->load->view('member/login');
                    //echo "wrong details";
                  }

              }

 }
 else
    {
        //echo "Already";
     redirect("Member_controller/dashboard");//calling employee register

    }
}
```

Logout code

```
function logout()

  {  
      $this->session->unset_userdata('login_session');
      $this->session->sess_destroy();
      redirect('Member_controller/index');
  }
```

Comment: have you started the session in config/autoload.php file?

Comment: @PHPGeek, Yes, I already added a session in the config autoload.php my code is $autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation','session','database','encryption','cart');

Answer (score 0):

When you logout from second tab that means you destroying you login session from browser. That`s  why on 1st tab when you refresh it shows that error. to avoid that error use:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('login_session'))
{
   redirect to login
}

//Dashboard
```

Updated :

```
public function index()
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('login_session'))
    {
      $this->checkLogin();
    }
    else
    {
      redirect("Member_controller/dashboard");//calling employee 
    }
}

  public function checkLogin()
  {
    if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')=='POST')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_id', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('member_password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
                $this->load->view('member/login');
        }
         else
        {

            $custid = $this->input->post('customer_id');
            $password = $this->input->post('member_password');
            $result=$this->Member_model->check_password($custid,$password);//varifying password
            if ($result) 
            {
                $login_emp_session = array('firstname' => $result->first_name,'lastname' => $result->last_name);
                $this->session->set_userdata('login_session',$login_emp_session);//set the session 
                redirect("Member_controller/dashboard");

            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid_password', 'Invalid username and password');
                $this->load->view('member/login');
           }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('member/login');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, Where should I use this code? should I use in the __construct?

Comment: Yes..instead of if(!($this->session->userdata('login_session'))).. Ow. In index(){ if(!$this->session->userdata('login_session')){//login call}else{//dashboard}}

Comment: I added your code in _construct if (!$this->session->userdata('login_session'))
        { 
         //$this->load->view('member/checkLogin');
        redirect("Member_controller/index");
        }.                                                     but it not working I mean ni network tab it's continue calling the index and at the end I am getting the error "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: and your second comment I tried that also but I am getting same issue

Comment: Give me some time to check.

Comment: There is one extra '}'  at the end and after logout I am not getting the login page.

Comment: Yes, Still getting the error. and now after log out I am not getting the login page

Comment: Added logout code and one more thing. within few second my session automatically log out.  I don't understand why this happing and then I am also getting the error " Message: Undefined index: login_session".